Python PyQt delete layouts and widgets
I have a issue removing widgets/layouts.
The function tries to update the panel according to what is in the dbo, when a script is inserted or deleted, I want the panel to show the changes, but it doesn't work quite right, the interface becomes a complete mess, this is my function:

After deleting/adding an element, this is how the interface looks like:

Here my code:
github/compliance_operative_control
if self.scripts_list_table is not None:
    while self.scripts_list_table.count():
        child = self.scripts_list_table.takeAt(0)
        if child.widget() is not None:
            child.widget().deleteLater()
            child.widget().setParent(None)
        elif child.layout() is not None:
            child.layout().deleteLater()
            child.layout().setParent(None)


I already found the solution, when you arrive to a layout, what you should do is to iterate that layout before deleting it, because widgets are not deleted together with the layout.
I copy the solution in case someone finds it useful:
def scripts_panel(self):
    if self.scripts_list_table is not None:
        while self.scripts_list_table.count():
            child = self.scripts_list_table.takeAt(0)
            if child.widget() is not None:
                child.widget().deleteLater()
            elif child.layout() is not None:
                while child.count():
                    subchild = child.takeAt(0)
                    subchild.widget().deleteLater()
                child.layout().deleteLater()


This just adds a further layer to what originally done, but doesn't consider layouts nested in multiple levels. A proper implementation should use recursion, with a basic function that accepts a target layout, delete its direct child widgets, and whenever it finds a child layout will call itself with that. Also, you're not considering spacer items.
